# Guardar en una constante global lo que retorna una función asíncrona

Tags: javascript, promesas, local-storage, async-await, tensorflow

**Explicación**

> Estoy desarrollando un proyecto con `Tensorflow JS`, en el que hasta el momento ya guardo el modelo en el `LocalStorage` si aun no ha sido entrenado por el usuario. Para ello, hice una función asíncrona para cargar el modelo. El detalle, es que lo que la función asincrona retorna, la estoy guardando en una constante global `model`. Sin embargo, me aparece el siguiente aviso: `model.predict is not a function`.

**Pruebas**

> Para corroborar que lo que estaba retornando funcionase, dentro de la función asincrona inserte un `model.predict` justo después de cargar el modelo, y aquí si me funciona, no me aparece ningún error, pero al momento de guardarlo en la constante global y utilizar el `model.predict` si me aparece el error.

```js
const model = cargar();

async function cargar() {
    let model;
    if (localStorage.getItem('modelo')) {
        model = await tf.loadLayersModel('localstorage://modelo');
        console.log('Cargado de localStorage: ', model);
    } else {
        model = tf.sequential();
        ... // Creación del modelo y entrenamiento
    }
    return model;
}
```

Apenas estoy comenzando a familiarizarme con las `Promesas`, me gustaría que me orientaran para solucionar este problema, muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Una función asíncrona siempre siempre siempre retorna una promesa. No puedes retornar otra cosa que no sea una promesa. Para consumir tus datos, usa `model.then(datos => {// consumelos aca})` después de que los cargas.

Comment: No se puede, no puedes hacer tal cosa, debes cambiar tu logica para adaptarla a un modelo asincrono.